# Excluding 'No Data' Pixels When Counting number of pixels in an AOI with ERDAS IMAGINE

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing

I'm working with Landsat imagery in ERDAS IMAGINE 2014 and have encountered an issue with 'no data' pixels within my Area of Interest (AOI). The AOI includes unwanted 'no data' pixels that are affecting my pixel count statistics. I need to accurately count the pixel values in my AOI, excluding these 'no data' pixels. The 'no data' pixels appear to be at the edges of the satellite image and in areas where the sensor did not capture data (possibly due to clouds or shadows).

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've checked the metadata to confirm the 'no data' value, which is set to a specific value (e.g., 0 or -9999).

I've attempted to use the Reclassify tool to change the 'no data' value and the Mask tool to exclude these pixels from the analysis.

However, I'm still seeing 'no data' pixels in my zonal statistics output. Here are my specific questions:

How can I ensure that ERDAS IMAGINE recognizes and excludes 'no data' pixels when calculating zonal statistics within an AOI?

Is there a way to automate the masking of these 'no data' pixels to streamline the process for multiple images?